# Published project files ignored

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I've been trying to publish my Visual Studio 2010 project. I do this by accessing a hard drive which corresponds to a URL, so X:\Options\Forms\HD\ corresponds to /HD. Yet when I go to the URL, it says I don't have a default.aspx page. Yet when I look in the corresponding file directory the default.aspx page is right there. Why is the browser ignoring it? Another issue I have is that not all of the files are getting published when I select the option in Visual Studio; many are left behind including my default.aspx.vb file.

Comment: Which server are you using? Is Default.aspx accessible if you access directly? If so, do you have Default.aspx configured as a default document? Probably it's not the browser who ignores Default.aspx but more likely a wrong configuration of your web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure files get published, make sure that they have the correct Build Action set (check the Properties window for the file). Especially, if it is set to None or if the files are not part of the solution/project they won't get published. The "Content" build action is a good choice for any file that just needs to be published.

Extra tip: for files that VS doesn't know the default build action is None. You can however configure VS to use whatever build action you want.

I've written about it here: http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2010/07/02/Visual-Studio-default-build-action-for-non-default-file-types.aspx
Also, I've created a simple tool that generates the necessary configuration file: http://tools.andreloker.de/dbag